# Finding a Word in a textbox using vba

Tags: vba, outlook

Hello I am trying to do a search for a word in a text box. Once that word is found I want the system to find the next 7 words following the found word. Basically, each time a paragarph will be copied in this textbox and there is one word (User ID:) will always be there. But a different user id will be entered following the word "User ID:" every time. I would like to automate this to the system to find out. I am able to find the word "User ID" with the code below. But I am not sure how get the actual user id that follows it.

```
Dim Search, Where
' Get search string from user.
Search = "User ID:"
' Find string in text.
Where = InStr(TxtWebForm.Text, Search)
If Where Then
    TxtWebForm.SetFocus
    TxtWebForm.SelStart = Where - 1
    TxtWebForm.SelLength = Len(Search)
Else
    MsgBox "String not found."
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look for the next 9 spaces (seven words plus the one space in "User ID" plus the one space after "User ID").

```
Private Sub txtWebForm_Change()

    Dim Search As String
    Dim Where As Long
    Dim LastSpace As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Search = "User ID:"
    Where = InStr(1, Me.txtWebForm.Text, Search)
    LastSpace = Where

    For i = 1 To (7 + 2)
        LastSpace = InStr(LastSpace + 1, Me.txtWebForm.Text, Space(1))
    Next i

    With Me.txtWebForm
        .SetFocus
        .SelStart = Where - 1
        .SelLength = LastSpace - .SelStart
    End With

End Sub
```